# Should I be forcing everything into a numpy array just because I want the convenient indexing and slicing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my current project I need to keep track of multiple lists which store properties of a collection of "things". The lists are ordered such that the ith element of each list represents a property of the ith "thing".

My "things" are actually binary images in OpenCV. I have one list where each element is a 2D numpy array representing the binary image. I have another list with the contours of those binary images. Another one with the hierarchy of those contours. Another one with an index which helps me order these things. And another one with... Well even if you don't use OpenCV, you probably get the point.

So in order to easily work with slices of these lists, I try to make them all into numpy arrays. But I do have to do funny work arounds. A particular example is when my code broke just because numpy will numpify a list of lists with consistent lengths differently than it numpifies a list of lists with varying lengths.

Here's what I mean:

```
ls1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2]]
np.array(ls1)
>>> array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 2])], dtype=object)

ls2 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
np.array(ls2)
>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

**To get to the point**, I get the feeling numpy didn't want me to use it this way. Am I doing a reasonable thing here? Or is there a better way for me to keep track of multiple lists in parallel and easily retrieve/reassign slices of them?

**EDIT**

Upon request here is a minimal example of what I am really trying to do.

```
# I have a list of binary images, each with different size
# pretend there are 100 of them
ls_binaries = [binary1, binary2, binary100]


# I want to know if they have some property "foo"
ls_has_foo = [has_foo(binary) for binary in ls_binaries]

# At some other point I want to know if they have some property "bar"
ls_has_bar = [has_bar(binary) for binary in ls_binaries]

# Maybe at some point later I want to retrieve all binaries 
# which have foo but not bar
# but I can only do it this way if binaries is a numpy array
arr_binaries = np.array(ls_binaries)
binaries_which_have_foo_but_not_bar = arr_binaries[np.bitwise_and(ls_has_foo, ~ls_has_bar)]

# And maybe I'll want to do it again at some other point later
# but in a slightly different way.
```

And one more example from the comments: Here's what I do to order a bunch of contours from left to right. The contours may have different lengths but this works nicely:

```
x_coords = np.array([np.min(el[:,:,0]) for el in contours])
cnt_sort = np.argsort(x_coords)
```

Comment: `[[1,2,3], [1,2]]` <-- this is probably not a sensible thing to put into a numpy array unless you plan to pad the shorter sublists

Comment: @Dan yes I've discovered that and it has been painful. But instead of not numpifying, I do it anyway with a workaround. Because it's still worth having the awesome indexing/slicing and I don't know of a better alternative.

Comment: It might be better if you could make a minimal example of what you are trying to do with the data

Comment: I agree with @Dan. I was thinking of answering with some examples showing how I use pandas dataframes to handle problems that seem similar to me. But it's hard to know for sure without something a bit more concrete. (Still, this is an interesting and worthwhile question IMO.)

Comment: In the example you've provided you lose basically all the benefits of numpy slicing.  Look at the shape of the array created.

Comment: @user3483203 well actually there is a use case where it's still very useful. One of my lists is a set of contours, and I want to order those contours from left to right so I do this: `x_coords = np.array([np.min(el[:,:,0]) for el in contours])`. Even though the contours have different lengths, the slicing comes in handy.

Comment: For that example you would be better off padding with `inf`, you'd get the same result but be able to use the vectorized calculation.  Again, it's difficult to give correct advice without a better example of what you need to do.

Comment: An array of 'things' is an object dtype array.  Functionally that's a lot like a list.  Iteration is slower than with a list.  Indexing is a bit nicer, esp. if 2d.  But it doesn't do fast math like numeric arrays.  And as you note it can be tricky to create (with the simple `np.array(alist)` call).

Comment: @user3483203 thanks for the padding tipoff. I tried to add some more context to the OP. The first time I was motivated to do this was when I found that the opencv contours and hierarchy needed to be preserved intact in order to not lose the hierarchical properties. So instead of straight up filtering and sorting, I started maintaining lists of booleans and ints for the filters and sorts so that I could retrieve the results of those filters and sorts whenever I needed them but still keep the original lists of contours and hierarchies intact. Doing it all without numpy would be 5x lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting your minimal example:

Your two `has` tests produce boolean lists:

```
In [331]: l1, l2 = [True,False,False], [True,True,False]
```

They can be combined with the array function:

```
In [332]: np.bitwise_and(l1,l2)          
Out[332]: array([ True, False, False])


In [333]: ls = ['foo','bar','baz']
```

object dtype indexing:

```
In [334]: np.array(ls,object)                                                                  
Out[334]: array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], dtype=object)
In [335]: np.array(ls,object)[_332]                                                            
Out[335]: array(['foo'], dtype=object)
```

equivalent list 'indexing':

```
In [336]: [x for x,y in zip(ls, _332) if y]                                                    
Out[336]: ['foo']
```

list equivalent for the bitwise_and:

```
In [338]: [(x and y) for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]                                                    
Out[338]: [True, False, False]
```

If you start with lists, it is often best to stick with lists.  Array operations like `bitwise_and` and indexing can be fast, but creating arrays first takes some time.

Object dtype arrays occupy an awkward middle ground between lists and arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose the list indexing is useful to know about, although I'm not sure it will be practical on all the different cases I want to apply it. My example was "minimal" but it gets a little more complicated in practise.

Comment: You'll need to do your own time testing.